# Using a ServerSocket without port forwarding?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, port

This may be a stupid question, but here goes. 
Im writing this chat program, where there is a server, and clients that can connect to it. I want to implement private messaging into the program, but I don't know how to get the clients to directly connect to eachother. For the server, I used a ServerSocket, which runs on a single port. To get that to work, I needed to forward a port to the server. Is there a way to get the clients to wait for connections, without forwarding a port to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of TCP/IP is that a single client connects to a predefined port on a server. So yes, you'll also need to have a `ServerSocket` on the client that's going to accept the direct connection. You'll almost always run into trouble with port forwarding and the like, which is why UPnP was invented one day.

What you are trying to do is 'peer to peer' connectivity, aka P2P, which is always, by its very definition, plagued by firewalling problems. As such it's usually, especially for a chat, easier to use the central server as 'switchboard' server and relay the private messages as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've written not long time ago a template for `multiple client - server` application, that might help you to solve your problem. The rest of your question was already answerd by @Niels, I think ;)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class ServeConnection extends Thread {
        private Socket socket = null;
        private BufferedReader in = null;
        private PrintWriter out = null;

        public ServeConnection(Socket s) throws IOException {

                // init connection with client
                socket = s;
                try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        this.socket.getInputStream()));
                        out = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O.");
                        System.exit(1);
                }                
                start();
        }

        public void run() {

                System.out.println("client accepted from: " + socket.getInetAddress()
                                + ":" + socket.getPort());

           // get commands from client, until is he communicating or until no error
           // occurs
                String inputLine, outputLine;

                try {
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {


                                System.out.println("request: " + inputLine);
                                outputLine = inputLine;    
                                out.println("I've recived "+outputLine);                                 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("server ending");
                out.close();
                try {
                        in.close();
                        socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}

class Server {
        public static void svr_main(int port) throws IOException {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
                try {
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
                        System.exit(1);
                }

                System.out.println("Server ready");

                try {
                        while (true) {
                                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                                try {
                                        new ServeConnection(socket);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                        System.err.println("IO Exception");
                                }
                        }
                } finally {
                        serverSocket.close();
                }
        }
}

class Client {      
        static Socket echoSocket = null;
        static PrintWriter out = null;
        static BufferedReader in = null;





        public static void cli_main(int port, String servername) throws
IOException {
                try {
                        echoSocket = new Socket(servername, port);
                        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        echoSocket.getInputStream()));
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + servername);
                        System.exit(1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + servername);
                        System.exit(1);
                }

                System.out.println("Client ready!");
                while (true) {

                        inputLine = (in.readLine().toString());
                        if (inputLine == null) {
                                System.out.println("Client closing!");
                                break;
                        }

                        // get the input and tokenize it
                        String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");


                }

                out.close();
                in.close();
                echoSocket.close();
                System.out.println("Client closing");
        }
}

public class MyClientServerSnippet{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                if (args.length == 0) {
                        System.err.println("Client: java snippet.MyClientServerSnippet<hostname> <port>");
                        System.err.println("Server: java snippet.MyClientServerSnippet<port>");
                         System.exit(1);
                }
                else if (args.length > 1) {                   
                        System.out.println("Starting client...\n");
                        Client client = new Client();
                        client.cli_main(3049, "127.0.0.1");
                } else {
                        System.out.println("Starting server...\n");
                        Server server = new Server();
                        server.svr_main(3049);
                }
        }
}
```